# Ruby unexpected ':', expecting kEND

Tags: ruby, vagrantfile

I want to set up vagrant on my Ubuntu, when "vagrant up", it always give me the following error
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrantprov.sh"

I checked the Vagrantfile, it should be OK, can anyone tell me where the error is? Thanks.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrantprov.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Ruby are you running? The named args syntax (`path: "..."`) is supported from on 1.9 and above, perhaps you have a lower Ruby version?

(1.8)

```
1.8.7 :001 > puts "a", b: 1

SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

(1.9)

```
1.9.3p429 :001 > puts "a", b: 1
a
{:b=>1}
 => nil
```

Comment: My default ruby is 1.8.7, now I updated it to 1.9.1 and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ruby <1.9? Old fashioned hash syntax style is required for old Ruby version

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrantprov.sh"
```

Comment: My default ruby is 1.8.7, now I updated it to 1.9.1 and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby < 1.9 :

```
:a => 1
```

Ruby >= 1.9 :

```
a : 1
```