# getting syntax errors with react-native init

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I run "react-native init AwesomeProject" it finishes building the npm dependency tree then produces a list of init.sh errors. The resulting project only has the node_modules dir and package.json file in it. Here is the first `init.sh` error, which is followed by five more:

> /Users/SM/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/init.sh:8: syntax
> error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND
> .gsub("SampleApp", app_name)
> ^

I have XCode 4.6.3, is that related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error is to do with lower version of Ruby on your mac. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556683/ruby-unexpected-expecting-kend).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Ruby 2.2 is now working and a complete reactive-native project is now being generated :)